# How to set up simple static Ethernet connection?

Tags: networking

System A has Wi-Fi Internet access and an Ethernet port, while System B has just an Ethernet port. I connected the ports directly to each other. Both are fairly modern desktop PCs running Ubuntu 10.04.

On A I ran:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.1/24 dev eth0

$ ip route
10.66.225.0/24 dev ra0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.66.225.153  metric 2 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ra0  scope link  metric 1000 
default via 10.66.225.1 dev ra0  proto static
```

On B I ran:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0
```

However, when I now try to ping 192.168.0.2 from .1, I get:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
```

Any hints? TIA.

Comment: Please add the output of `tail /var/log/ufw.log` to rule out any inadvertent firewall behaviour (unlikely) and also the output from each box of `ifconfig -a` to inspect packet statistics. Finally, did you use a crossover cable, or are you relying on one of the NICs having crossover detection? Or when you said you connected them together, did you imply a hub/switch? In that case, what kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an Ethernet hub or switch to connect the two machines. If the machines are old then you can't use a conventional UTP cable to connect them.  (You can use a crossover cable.)  Even if the machines are new and are equipped with Auto-MDIX, what can happen is that both machines have their Ethernet ports switched off and niether one will switch its port on until connected to a peer with an enabled port.

Answer (score 0):

And like magic, I just pressed up enter to retry the same command again some 10m later, and it works. I'll still mark another answer as accepted if someone can explain why this happened.

**Update**: Just tried doing the same thing again, and once more I'm getting Destination Host Unreachable errors, except this time it's been hours and the problem hasn't gone away.

Comment: Any other Wi-Fi routers near you?

Comment: The packets to .2 are being sent to eth0, so Wi-Fi routers should be unrelated.